# How to edit the hosts to block IP address?

Tags: terminal, hosts

I know how to block certain website, like if I want to block google I can use this line in the host

```
0.0.0.0 www.google.com.hk
        www.google.com.hk
```

But my question is how can I block certain IP address? Like how can I block certain IP address like 17.154.66.79?

Comment: you need to know the URL !

Comment: @Buscar웃 That's the question... I don't know how to get URL like this.

Comment: juan cena!!!!!!!

Comment: do do do do do do

Comment: related: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/230209/how-do-i-drop-outgoing-packets-to-specific-host-port

Answer (score 3):

Technically, OS X can make use of `/etc/hosts.allow` and `/etc/hosts.deny` files that will  work with standard resolvable hostnames. For blocking IP addresses, using `iptables` is the usual method but apparently Apple deprecated its use beginning with Lion and switched to `pf` for this function. Check and read the links in [this thread on SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/688680/is-there-the-command-in-mac-os-x10-8-equivalent-to-iptables) for info on using `pf` and perhaps a GUI front-end for it.

Comment: hosts.allow and hosts.deny restrict access to your **own** Unix or Linux machine - even fine-grained to single services. [Source](http://its.virginia.edu/unixsys/sec/hosts.html)

Comment: @klanomath Certainly, using something like `deny tcp .google.com` to block TCP connections. `iptables` has fine-grained functions as well.

Comment: iftables/pf are effective means but hosts.allow/deny doesn't help much blocking **outgoing** traffic

Comment: @klanomath Yes, that would be better addressed through the router or external firewall. But it will kill the incoming response.

Answer (score 2):

Little Snitch (or similar) blocks IP addresses & IP Ranges for both outgoing & incoming connections.

Answer (score 0):

You may execute a reverse DNS lookup to determine a hostname you want to block.
Use a web service like [reverse DNS lookup](http://remote.12dt.com/) or 'nslookup' to get a hostname.

nslookup:

1. Start `Terminal.app` and enter `nslookup`
2. At the prompt enter `server 8.8.8.8` (this defines which dns-server to use to do the reverse DNS lookup. 8.8.8.8 is a google name server)
3. At the next prompt enter an ip-address
4. Now you'll get the host name you need for your `hosts` file

Example output:

```
user$ nslookup
> server 8.8.8.8
Default server: 8.8.8.8
Address: 8.8.8.8#53
> 93.220.102.55
Server:     8.8.8.8
Address:    8.8.8.8#53

Non-authoritative answer:
55.102.220.93.in-addr.arpa  name = p5DDC6637.dip0.t-ipconnect.de.
```

If you add `127.0.0.1   p5DDC6637.dip0.t-ipconnect.de` to your `hosts` file you will prevent your computer accessing my web server.

Caveats:

A lot of ip-addresses and correspondent host names can't be tied to a special computer/host. Mine change at least every 24 hours.

A today hazardous site/hostname might be a valuable one in the future but unaccessible for you.

Some ip-addresses are tied to several hostnames with the consequence that you won't be able to detect the name you actually want to block.

Comment: this is answering a different question: how to block access to a host-name or domain name. It will NOT work if someone will use the IP address directly (in the browser, or any other software that makes the TCP/IP connection,