# How to Use Terminal for "Little Snitch" Functionality without Little Snitch

Tags: terminal, macos, firewall, tcp

I'm a Terminal newb, and trying to wrap my head around manual "Little Snitch" functionality without using Little Snitch.

From the research I've been doing, I've landed on the fact that I need to utilize pf.conf, however I have no idea how to format my request for Terminal.

I need to block a connection to www.domain.com on port 443. How do I do this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To permanently block outgoing traffic to specific domains you should create a new anchor file and add it to pf.conf.

1. Create an anchor file *org.user.block.out* in /private/etc/pf.anchors

   ```
   sudo touch /private/etc/pf.anchors/org.user.block.out
   ```

   with the following content and a trailing empty line

   ```
   mybadhosts = "{ www.domain.com, domain.com, www.domain2.com, domain2.com }"
   mybadports = "{ 443, 80 }"

   block drop out proto tcp from any to $mybadhosts port $mybadports
   ```

   The additional domain names in mybadhosts are just an example how to add additional domains. The same goes for port 80 in mybadports.

   A simple but less flexible solution is:

   ```
   block drop out proto tcp from any to domain.com port 443
   ```
2. Modify the file /private/etc/pf.conf but keep a trailing empty line

   original file:

   ```
   scrub-anchor "com.apple/*"
   nat-anchor "com.apple/*"
   rdr-anchor "com.apple/*"
   dummynet-anchor "com.apple/*"
   anchor "com.apple/*"
   load anchor "com.apple" from "/etc/pf.anchors/com.apple"
   ```

   to

   ```
   scrub-anchor "com.apple/*"
   nat-anchor "com.apple/*"
   rdr-anchor "com.apple/*"
   dummynet-anchor "com.apple/*"
   anchor "com.apple/*"
   anchor "org.user.block.out"
   load anchor "com.apple" from "/etc/pf.anchors/com.apple"
   load anchor "org.user.block.out" from "/etc/pf.anchors/org.user.block.out"
   ```
3. Parse and test your anchor file to make sure there are no errors:

   ```
   sudo pfctl -vnf /etc/pf.anchors/org.user.block.out
   ```
4. Now modify /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.pfctl.plist from

   ```
   <array>
       <string>pfctl</string>
       <string>-f</string>
       <string>/etc/pf.conf</string>
   </array>
   ```

   to

   ```
   <array>
       <string>pfctl</string>
       <string>-e</string>
       <string>-f</string>
       <string>/etc/pf.conf</string>
   </array>
   ```

   You have to disable System Integrity Protection to accomplish this. After editing the file reenable SIP. After rebooting your Mac pf will be enabled (that's the -e option).

   Alternatively you may create your own launch daemon similar to the answer here: [Using Server 5.0.15 to share internet WITHOUT internet sharing](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/228936/using-server-5-0-15-to-share-internet-without-internet-sharing).

After a system update or upgrade some of the original files above may have been replaced and you have to reapply all changes.

Comment: my goodness that is a comprehensive answer.