# Automating pfctl to block incoming connections and IPs

Tags: network, security, firewall, ipfw

I get a lot of unwanted traffic from Chinese IP addresses. I'm using an old Mac with OS X 10.7.5 (my Mac is ancient, so I cannot update further), so I imagine it's more vulnerable than a newer Mac would be.

[This page](https://ikawnoclast.com/systems/firewall/mac-os-x-pf-firewall/) gave an *excellent* tutorial about how to use `pfctl` to detect sshd "attackers" who violate certain rules and add them to a blacklist. In my naive understanding, this applies only to `sshd` connections.

**How can I generalize that tutorial to block other kinds of traffic as well?** In particular, I have unwanted traffic involving `sshd`, `sshd-keygen-wrapper`, and `screensharingd`, though I'd love to block *any* traffic that has too many simultaneous connections or too many attempts within a certain amount of time.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply replace:

```
table <attackers> persist
block log quick from <attackers>
pass in quick proto tcp from any port ssh flags S/SA keep state (max-src-conn 3, max-src-conn-rate 5/60, overload <attackers> flush global)
```

with:

```
table <attackers> persist
block log quick from <attackers>
pass in quick proto tcp from any flags S/SA keep state (max-src-conn 3, max-src-conn-rate 5/60,  overload <attackers> flush global)
```

If you want to restrict this to single ports use: `... port {22, 443, 5900:5902} ...` instead of `... port ssh ...`.

Comment: Is this essentially what Little Snitch does?

Comment: @jvriesem No, LS does the opposite: it blocks **outgoing** requests based on apps (and decided by the user).  pfctl blocks **incoming** requests (in the above example).

Comment: Is there a general way to do this for incoming and outgoing...or is that a separate question? (thanks again!)

Comment: @jvriesem This is a separate question, yes. It can be done with pfctl but it's a **real** hassle compared to Little Snitch.

Comment: @jvriesem At the moment you can get LS for ~$10, but it's a bit complicated and some basic knowledge of the German language is required. You have to buy a german PDF for 8,95 € which entitles you to register LS and some other macOS apps for free with your email address.

Comment: @jvriesem [How to Use Terminal for “Little Snitch” Functionality without Little Snitch](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/230526/93229). My answer there is a simple example with http/https traffic and some domains only. If you want to block outgoing traffic for more apps (=ports) profound knowledge of the ports used and the external sites targeted is required and the org.user.block.out gets **really** large and confusingly complex (unübersichtlich is a better German word with no direct English translation).